# ThreeJS: How to mark a spot on a rigged mesh?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I would like to create a user experience with ThreeJS where a user can click on a mesh to add markers onto it. These markers will sit on the surface of the mesh, and follow the mesh as it deforms with the armature inside it. This armature has some complex animations that deform in ways that are not simple to replicate by applying transformations directly to the marker positions.

How can I accomplish something like this? So far the best ideas I've come up with are:

- Adding a new bone specifically for each marker, but the challenge with this would be determining programmatically which existing bone to parent it to, so as to ensure that it inherits the correct deformations.
- Is there some way to assign specific vertices within a mesh to a variable? If so, I haven't been able to find any examples of something like this.
- Perhaps there is some solution involving texture maps, but I'd like to avoid that if possible as my app currently does not require any texture maps and I'd like to avoid introducing them.

Thoughts?

Comment: In my idle thoughts, I'm now thinking that the first solution is best: adding a bone to the armature as a marker. I can just parent the new bone to whichever bone in the armature is the closest, and that should PROBABLY work as expected 99% of the time. The only edge case would be if the marker is placed while the armature is contorted in such a way that some other bone (say a finger bone) is invading the part of the mesh where the marker is being placed. There are probably ways to segment the mesh into regions to mitigate this. Will think more...

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's more than one way do this, and hopefully some are simpler than this, but here's what I came up with:

1. Collect `pointClicked` (world space position returned by raycaster) and the vertex indices for the triangle that was clicked (`face` returned by raycaster).

```js
if ( intersection.length > 0 ) {

  const {face, point, object} = intersection[0];
  
  // vertex indices for clicked triangle
  const {a, b, c} = face;
  const mesh = object;

  // ...
```

2. Compute weights [0,1] representing how strongly each of those vertices should affect the marker position, based on relative position of the point clicked. Weights (also called "barycentric coordinates") must sum to 1.

```js
const geometry = mesh.geometry;
const position = geometry.attributes.position;

// find local position (without skinning) of each vertex.
const basePA = new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(position, a);
const basePB = new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(position, b);
const basePC = new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(position, c);

// find local position (with skinning) of each vertex.
const skinnedPA = mesh.boneTransform(a, basePA.clone());
const skinnedPB = mesh.boneTransform(b, basePB.clone());
const skinnedPC = mesh.boneTransform(c, basePC.clone());

// compute barycentric coordinates for clicked point.
const localPoint = mesh.worldToLocal(point.clone());
const barycoord = THREE.Triangle.getBarycoord(localPoint, skinnedPA, skinnedPB, skinnedPC, new THREE.Vector3()).toArray();
```

3. Compute the base position of the marker, pre-skinning.

```js
const localPosition = new THREE.Vector3()
  .addScaledVector(basePA, barycoord[0])
  .addScaledVector(basePB, barycoord[1])
  .addScaledVector(basePC, barycoord[2]);
```

4. Given those weights and vertices, compute which bones should influence the marker position, and by how much, by summing the bone influences of each vertex and applying the weights.

```js
// Array of [boneIndex, boneWeight] pairs.
const weights = getInterpolatedWeights(mesh, [a, b, c], barycoord);

function getInterpolatedWeights(mesh, face, barycoord) {
    const weightMap = new Map();

    const geometry = mesh.geometry;

    const skinIndex = new THREE.Vector4();
    const skinWeight = new THREE.Vector4();

    const skinIndexList = [0, 0, 0, 0];
    const skinWeightList = [0, 0, 0, 0];

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        skinIndex.fromBufferAttribute(geometry.attributes.skinIndex, face[i]).toArray(skinIndexList);
        skinWeight.fromBufferAttribute(geometry.attributes.skinWeight, face[i]).toArray(skinWeightList);

        for (let j = 0; j < skinIndexList.length; j++) {
            const index = skinIndexList[j];
            let weight = weightMap.has(index) ? weightMap.get(index) : 0;
            weight += skinWeightList[j] * barycoord[i];

            if (weight > 0) {
                weightMap.set(index, weight);
            }
        }
    }

    return Array.from(weightMap.entries());
}
```

5. On each frame of animation, use these bone weights to recompute the position of the marker, relative to the skeleton.

```js
const _basePosition = new THREE.Vector3();
const _skinnedPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
const _matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
const _vector = new THREE.Vector3();

// ...

_basePosition.copy(localPosition).applyMatrix4(mesh.bindMatrix);
_skinnedPosition.set(0, 0, 0);

// Compute influence of each bone on the marker position.
for (const [boneIndex, boneWeight] of weights) {
  _matrix.multiplyMatrices(
    mesh.skeleton.bones[boneIndex].matrixWorld,
    mesh.skeleton.boneInverses[boneIndex]
  ); 

  _skinnedPosition.addScaledVector(
    _vector.copy(_basePosition).applyMatrix4(_matrix),
    boneWeight
  );
}

_skinnedPosition.applyMatrix4(mesh.bindMatrixInverse);

// Assuming the marker is added to the scene, not as a child
// of the model, we need to convert this position into world space.
mesh.localToWorld(_skinnedPosition);

markerMesh.position.copy(_skinnedPosition);
```

Comment: Possible simplification: stash the barycentric coords and triangle index as Don described, but for the "On each frame of animation" part, simply call `Mesh.getVertexPosition` three times (one for each triangle corner) and apply barycentric interpolation to the get the current marker position.  The `getVertexPosition` method does all the skinning math for you, so you don't need to mess with bones and such.